# grep on certain columns

Tags: shell

I'm on an ftps server using lftp. When I run ls, I get something like this (with no additional flags):

```
02-19-18  11:32AM       <DIR>          Wingdings
01-31-18  05:17PM       <DIR>          Dongles
02-20-18  08:21AM       <DIR>          Dingbats
02-20-18  09:42AM                      Foobars
01-25-18  11:19AM                      Coolcats
02-13-18  02:51AM                      McDonald
```

I'm trying to get all the folders or directories that have a capital letter D in the name, so I ran:

```
lftp xxx@xxx:/> ls | grep D
02-19-18  11:32AM       <DIR>          Wingdings
01-31-18  05:17PM       <DIR>          Dimwits
02-20-18  08:21AM       <DIR>          Dingbats
02-13-18  02:51AM                      McDonald
```

I only expected to get Dimwits and Dingbats, but I also got Wingdings because of the `<DIR>` in the line. I know I could just run:

```
lftp xxx@xxx:/> ls | awk {\'print $4\'} | grep D
Dimwits
Dingbats
McDonald
```

But this truncates the first three columns, which I want.

Is there a way to do this:

```
lftp xxx@xxx:/> ****** some magical command ******
01-31-18  05:17PM       <DIR>          Dimwits
02-20-18  08:21AM       <DIR>          Dingbats
02-13-18  02:51AM                      McDonald
```

Comment: Note: I removed two tags, both of which were inappropriate. Please take the time to read the description before applying them.

Comment: only 1 accepted answer? Are your Questions that unique?

Comment: Why not use `ls D*`

Comment: @anubhava where is the grep? I just ran this and it gave me nothing.

Comment: Using `awk` it will be: `ls | awk '$NF ~ /^D/'`

Comment: @anubhava thanks, this works. Can you write as an answer with explanation?

Comment: For `McDonald` @anubhava needs `ls | awk '$NF ~ /D/'`.

Answer (score 0):

The right command to list files and dirs is :

```
lftp xxx@xxx:/> glob -a echo *D*
```

Output:

```
Dongles Dingbats DIR DIR DIR...
```

this list files and dirs (`-a`) and doesn't require parsing `ls` !

Check :

```
man lftp | less +/glob
```

And [**don't parse ls output !**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I already got this result. I'm looking for those files with the left three columns as well as stated in question.

Comment: yup, it doesn't give me any results actually. just blank.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right dir and use the right command ? (case sensitive) ? is there the `glob` command in your `man lftp` ? LFTP | Version 4.8.3 do the trick

Comment: With the -a, it gets me only the dir/file name column. I explicitly stated in the question that I wanted all columns.

Comment: Dunno what you are trying to do, but it's not reliable, especially if you have spaces in dirs or file names

Answer (score 0):

I can ask you to try with the below command:-

```
lftp xxx@xxx:/> ls | grep "*D???"
```

Comment: Sorry, I need a more generalized solution. I have updated the question.

Comment: Ok, will the last letter always be ends with `s`?

Comment: No. This is fake data. I am running this for real in production with lots of folders, files, and filters. I've updated the question again to illustrate this point.

Answer (score 0):

To get only the line that contains the string in a given column and get all columns of this line as result use this:

```
 ls | awk '($3 == "<DIR>" && $4 ~ /D/) || ($3 != "<DIR>" && $3 ~ /D/) { print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to find a D in the last field, look for a D without a fieldsep after it. I think you need tabs, I have tested it with spaces:

```
lftp xxx@xxx:/> ls | grep -E "D[^ \t]*$"
```